# Is there such thing as an Activity crash?

Tags: android, android-activity, crash, segmentation-fault, application-restart

I'm experiencing a very strange crash which is leaving my app running in a broken state. After getting the "Unfortunately, your app as stopped" message, the app doesn't go away but seems to just kick me back to the parent activity, as if only the activity crashed. However, I don't think that's a thing. Maybe it is somehow auto-restarting but without proper initialization. Can anyone shed some light on this?

I believe this is the error that is causing the crash:

```
A/libc: invalid address or address of corrupt block 0x8001a1e0 passed to dlfree
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 27143 (Loader:audio/mp)
```

Comment: Are you creating objects in a loop ( i.e running out of memory )

Comment: Nope, pretty sure I'm not doing that anywhere.